# How to insert parsed XML data in to a TextView

Tags: java, android, xml, parsing, textview

At the moment my parser parses data and stores it in a listView which can be displayed easily.

However I want to use a textView to display this data instead but I'm not sure how.

Here's the code that works using a listview:

```
public class StatisticsScreen extends ListActivity{

private List<Message> messages;
ListView lv;
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.statisticsscreen);    
    loadFeed();            
    lv = (ListView) findViewById(android.R.id.list);

    private void loadFeed() {
    try{
        BaseFeedParser parser = new BaseFeedParser();
        messages = parser.parse();
        List<String> titles = new ArrayList<String>(messages.size());
        for (Message msg : messages){
            titles.add(msg.getTemperature());
            titles.add(msg.getRain());
            titles.add(msg.getWind());
        }
        ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = 
            new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, R.layout.xmldatarow,titles);
        getListView().addHeaderView(View.inflate(this, R.layout.xmllayout, null));
        this.setListAdapter(adapter);
    } catch (Throwable t){
        Log.e("AndroidNews",t.getMessage(),t);
    }       
}
```

So like I said this works perfectly, but I want to use a TextView instead of a ListView to store/display the data..

Any advice?

EDIT: HERE'S THE SOLUTION

Here's the updated code that works now:

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.statisticsscreen);        
    tv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.xmltextview);      
    tv1 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.xmltextview1);
    tv2 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.xmltextview2);
    loadFeed();

    private void loadFeed() {
      try{
        BaseFeedParser parser = new BaseFeedParser();
        messages = parser.parse();
        for (Message msg : messages){
            tv.setText(msg.getTemperature());
            tv1.setText(msg.getRain());
            tv2.setText(msg.getWind());
         }           
      } catch (Throwable t){
         Log.e("Weather",t.getMessage(),t);
      }       
    }
 }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code cannot work because you are always replacing your textview with the last massage information. you should do this:

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
  super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
  setContentView(R.layout.statisticsscreen);        
  tv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.xmltextview);      
  loadFeed();

  private void loadFeed() {
    try {
      BaseFeedParser parser = new BaseFeedParser();
      messages = parser.parse();
      StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
      for (Message msg : messages){
        builder.append(msg.getTemperature());
        builder.append(",");
        builder.append(msg.getRain());
        builder.append(",");
        builder.append(msg.getWind());
        builder.append("\n");
      }
      tv.setText(builder.toString());
    } catch (Throwable t){
      Log.e("AndroidNews",t.getMessage(),t);
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Hey I updated my post with an edit there, could you have a look again please? Also, that method above, do I replace my loadFeed() with this or how do I use it? Thanks Ronan

Comment: Fixed! Thanks for your input, Ronan.

Comment: I see what you mean. Thanks again

Answer (score 1):

You'll need to format your data in some way and then use TextView's `setText()` method. If you want HTML-like formatting, you will find the `android.text.Html.fromHtml()` method useful.

Comment: Could you check out my edit? That might clarify how I want to structure my data..Ronan